# The issue of cutting the bottom of the text if you use isDense on the dropdown button of the flutter

Tags: flutter

I made Dropdown Button,

I wanted to narrow the gap with the title text

Used 'isDense = true' to remove padding.

However, the bottom of the text is not visible.

I want to make the whole text visible, but I want to get rid of padding, is there any way?

[what i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxPQU.png)

[what i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcuXI.png)

here is code what i write

```
DropdownButton(
          isDense: true,
          isExpanded: true,
          value: controller.selected,
          items: controller.menuList 
              .map(
                (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text(
                    e,
                    style: widget.menuTextStyle ??
                        kTextMainStyle.copyWith(
                          fontSize: kTextMiddleSize,
                        ),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            controller.onChanged(value as String);
          },
        )
```

I wrapped the text in padding and margin

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@kim,

**I've resolved those issues by adopting an alternative method**

```
 SizedBox(
          width: 200,
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: 'abc',
            itemHeight: 60,
            items: ['abc', 'xyz', 'hel']
                .map(
                  (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: e,
                    child: Text(
                      e,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              // controller.onChanged(value as String);
            },
          ),
        ),
```

**OR**

```
Container(
          width: 200,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                  width: 2.0,
                  color: Colors.blue), // Bottom border with spacing
            ),
          ),
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            isDense: true,
            underline: const SizedBox(),
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = newValue!;
              });
            },
            items: <String>[
              'abc',
              'xyz',
              'hel',
            ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

I hope this will help you.

Thank you.